# how to display one view in front of keyboard in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios7, keyboard, uitextview

[image]

Display back of keyboard .thanks for help.

```
UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0];
UIView* keyboard;
for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++)
{
    keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    // keyboard view found; add the custom button to it
    if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"UIKeyboard"] == YES)
        [keyboard addSubview:view_FriendsDropDownVIew];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyboard appears in a separated window from your main one, so if you do this:

```
NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
```

You'll get 2 `UIWindow`. The first one if your normal app, the second one is the keyboard.

Just add the view to the last one.

You can't add something to your main app UIWindow and expect to be on top of the keyboard because the UIWindow where the keyboard is placed is on top of that one.

Answer (score 0):

@Antonio MG answer's in `Swift2` :

```
let view = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.count-1]
```